# Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade from 15.10 problem

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit computer to 16.04.  I was initially prompted to do this via a message under the Unity graphical front end but got the message `Could not determine the upgrade`.  I looked though a few previous questions posted on this site and tried upgrading via these three commands:

```
sudo apt-get update –fix-missing
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo update-manager -d
```

However after doing all of this the 'About this computer' pull-down system window shows the operating system as still being 15.10 whereas the command (issued via a terminal):

```
lsb_release -a
```

shows that it is 16.04.  Also, when I enter the command:

```
unity --version
```

I get 7.3.3 and not 7.4 which, I understand,  is supposed to be the updated version with Ubuntu 16.04.  I ran Synaptic Package Manager but this says that that 7.3.3 is the most recent version.  It appears that I can ask the Ubuntu Software Center to install Unity version 8 but I have not done this because I think that there may be an underlying problem.

In summary, it seems that I have a mix of 16.04 and 15.10 and if anyone can suggest how to resolve this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt dist-upgrade

I think you should always try to avoid the '-d' argument as it refers to development releases and may bring instability

Comment: Thanks - I tried the suggested commands.  However, both sudo apt-get upgrade and  sudo apt dist-upgrade produced the answer  '0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade'.            Clearly it thinks that the system is up-to date but 'about this computer' on the Unity interface still shows the operating system as 15.10 and up-to date whereas the command line shows it as 16.04

Comment: Try sudo su, rm -rf /etc/grub.d,  apt autoremove, apt autoclean, apt -f install, dpkg --configure -a, apt update, apt upgrade, apt dist-upgrade, apt autoremove, update-grub

Comment: Thanks for then suggestion  -    I used the commands that  suggested which all worked ok until the last: 
sudo update-grub

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting

Comment: Thanks -    I used the commands suggested which all worked ok until the last:
**sudo update-grub** which generated the error *Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file*.   I used  the the **boot-repair** utility under Unity which generated the message *Boot successfully repaired ….  You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk)*.  I rebooted the PC and this proceeded ok but the original  error remained.  Should I create a /boot partition (and a /home??)

Comment: lsb_release -a, after executing this command do you now get Ubuntu 16.04? First tell me that. First problem first

Comment: @True_Grit Please answer

Answer (score 0):

While trying to recover from a failed upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 using your method, the same thing happened here when I did upgrade-grub: I got the same error message : Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.

I discovered that the new grub.cfg file was still referencing the old kernel from 16.04, and my /etc/grub.d directory had been restored, but not populated! Fortunately, I had not shut down or restarted, and I had a backup of /etc. After replacing the contents of the directory, "update-grub" worked.